# Programmatic way to find the cluster version from CDSW - Cloudera Data Science Workbench

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-cdp

Is there any programmatic way to find out the cluster version(CDH6 or CDP7) from a CDSW session?
Could any environment variable give a fool-proof way to determine the cluster version?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cloudera rest apis to achieve this.
https://:7180/api/v43/cm/version

Result:

{
"version" : **version**,
"buildUser" : "jenkins",
"buildTimestamp" : "20180402-2150",
"gitHash" : "4adcd280dde9c492680ada3ee369b4e97d22137a",
"snapshot" : false
}

API docs : https://archive.cloudera.com/cm7/7.2.4/generic/jar/cm_api/apidocs/index.html